# AttributeError: module 'torchmetrics' has no attribute 'IoU'

Tags: attributeerror

I'm newbie so be kind to me please.

```
self.metrics = torchmetrics.IoU(num_classes=n_classes)
```

[image]

I don't know how to use jaccard.

Comment: Please try to rewrite this into a question, such as “I tried xyz and expected abc but got 123”. Also, please update your answer to explain how it addresses your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
from torchmetrics import JaccardIndex    
self.metrics = JaccardIndex(task='multiclass',num_classes=n_classes)
```